# Minimizing area difference between concave hull and convex hull

Tags: convex-hulls, clustering

Suppose I have multiple n-dimensional data points. The area difference between its concave hull and convex hull is larger than a certain desired threshold. Is there an algorithm that can cluster the data points to `m` clusters so that the sum of area difference between its concave hull and convex hull for each cluster is minimized to be lower than a certain threshold, but at the same time keeping the cluster count `m` as small as possible?